# Partial derivative of the inverse of a linear operator

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Define a function $P:\mathbb S^{n\times n}\rightarrow \mathbb S^{n\times n}$ and a function $Q:\mathbb S^{n\times n}\rightarrow \mathbb S^{n\times n}$. We have a linear operator $L$ such that 
$$
LP=Q
$$
Assume the linear operator is invertible, then
$$
P=L^{-1}Q
$$
Define the partial derivative operator $\partial_a=\frac{\partial }{\partial a}$.

Is the following equation correct (or need any more conditions)?
$$
\partial_a P=L^{-1}\partial_a LL^{-1} Q-L^{-1}\partial_aQ
$$

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Is $L$ constant?
 It doesn't take a lot to convince yourself that the proof of the Leibniz rule generalises to any ring structure, so $\partial_a Q=\partial_a (LP)=(\partial_a L)P+L(\partial_a P).$ So you see the commutator of $\partial_a$ and multiplication by $L$ is exactly multiplication by $\partial_a L$, so no, the operators don't commute, unless $L$ is constant.

Of course, $L L^{-1}Q=Q,$ so $\partial_a (LL^{-1}Q)=\partial_a Q,$ automatically.

Comment: Of course, you could be in the situation that for your particular $P$, $(\partial_a L)P=0,$ in which case, you would have that the operators commute on $P$.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I am a bit confused. $P=L^{-1}Q$ so we have $\partial_a P=\partial_a (L^{-1}Q)=\partial_a(L^{-1})Q+L^{-1}\partial_aQ$, but $L^{-1}$ itself is a linear operator. How can I put a linear operator to another linear operator? I am a very beginner hah. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm asking where $L$ is defined. Let $Map(\mathbb{S}^{n\times n})$ denote the set of maps from $\mathbb{S}^{n\times n}$ into itself.
 Is it then true that $L:\mathbb{S}^{n\times n}\to \mathbb{S}^{n\times n}$ or that $L:Map(\mathbb{S}^{n\times n})\to \mathbb{S}^{n\times n}$, i.e., is $L$ allowed to be a different linear map depending on which point I'm evaluating $P$ and $Q$ in?

Comment: $L$ is defined as $LP=A^TP+PA$ where $A:\mathbb R^{n\times n}\rightarrow \mathbb R^{n\times n}$

Comment: In either case, you can view $L$ as a map from $Map(\mathbb{S}^{n\times n})$ (this is equivalent to $L$ being constant), and these maps have well-defined partial derivatives, because which map you pick depends on which point in $\mathbb{S}^{n\times n}$ we are evaluating in.

Comment: Then you are golden, and the operators commute.

Comment: A more elementary proof would be that if $S$ and $a$ are symmetric matrices, then $\frac{1}{t}(LP(S+ta)-LP(S))=L(\frac{1}{t}(P(S+ta)-P(s)))$ by linearity, and the left hand side tends to $(\partial_a LP)(S)$, while the right hand side tends to $L(\partial_aP)(S)$.

Comment: Many many thanks! Now the question is that you say $\partial_a Q=\partial_a (LP)=(\partial_a L)P+L(\partial_a P).$  I don't understand the meaning of $(\partial_a L)P$. $L$ is an operator itself but why we can put a linear operator $L$ to a differential operator $\partial_a$. The last part $L(\partial_a P)$ means a function $P$ after a differential operator $\partial_a$ and then after a linear operator $L$. What does $(\partial_a L)P$ mean?

Comment: I check the answer to the question and find that it is actually not commuting, but your answer is correct. I have edited the question and thanks again. Please help the above question...

Comment: I post a new question that can be seen here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3290022/partial-derivative-to-a-linear-operator