# Partial derivative to a linear operator

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Define a linear operator

$$
LP=A^TP+PA,
$$
where $A:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^{m\times m}$ and $P:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb S^{m\times m}$

Define a differential operator $\partial_ k=\partial /\partial k$ where $k\in\mathbb R$, i.e. $\partial_k A=\frac{\partial A(k)}{\partial k}$

Is the following equation correct?

$$
\partial_k(LP)=(\partial_k L)P
+L(\partial_k P)
$$

If it is correct, the question is what is the meaning of $(\partial_k L)P$. $L$ is an operator itself but why we can put a linear operator $L$ to a differential operator $\partial_k$. The last part $L(\partial_k P)$ means a function $P$ after a differential operator $\partial_k$ and then after a linear operator $L$. What does $(\partial_k L)P$ mean?

---

New edit

I notice if $(\partial_k L)P$ is defined as

$$
(\partial_k L)P = (\partial_k A^T)P+P(\partial_k A),
$$

the above equation is correct. But I can't find a solid reason why it should be defined like this.

Comment: What is $\mathbb S$ here?

Comment: real symmetric matrix

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac{\partial}{\partial k}$? Is $k$ an arbitrary unit vector?

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed: because $L$ has $\Bbb R^{m \times m}$ as its domain, $\partial_k L$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have edited the question and now it is a scalar case. $L$ is a linear operator so should not the domain and codomain be $Map(\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^{m\times m})\rightarrow Map(\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^{m\times m})$ ?

Comment: You’re right, that’s a clear oversight on my part. I suspect that your $\partial_k L$ is correct, but I also am not quite sure how to justify it.

Comment: By “currying”, you could also think of $L$ as a map that separately take a parameter from $\Bbb R$ ($\Bbb R^n$ in the original version of the question) and a parameter from $\Bbb R^{m\times m}$. From this perspective, your $\partial_k$ is a derivative with respect to this scalar parameter.

Comment: I think the problem is because of the symbol. By operator multiplication definition, $(AB)x=A(Bx)$, the equation $\partial_k(LP)=(\partial_k L)P
+L(\partial_k P)$ is not correct. But I can denote it as $\partial_k(LP)=L_k P
+L(\partial_k P)$, where $L_k = (\partial_k A^T)P+P(\partial_k A)$. That seems better and reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think this directly answers the question, but I’m leaving it as a long comment.

One approach here to compute the partial derivative is as follows: for $v \in \Bbb R^n$,
$$
\partial_k(LP)(v) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{LP(v + tk) - LP(v)}{t} = \\
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{A^T(v+tk)P(v + tk) + P(v + tk)A(v+tk) - 
A^T(v)P(v) + P(v)A(v)}{t} = \\
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{(A(v) + t\partial_k A)^T (P(v) + t\partial_k P(v)) + 
(P(v) + t\partial_k P(v))(A(v) + t\partial_kA) - 
A^T(v)P(v) + P(v)A(v)}{t} = \\
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t[(\partial_k A(v))^TP(v) + A(v) \partial_kP(v) + P(v) \partial_k A(v)  + \partial_k P(v) A(v)] + o(t)}{t} =\\
(\partial_k A(v))^TP(v) + A(v) \partial_kP(v) + P(v) \partial_k A(v)  + \partial_k P(v) A(v)
$$

Comment: I have edited the question, and now it is a scalar case. $L$ is a linear operator so should not the domain and codomain be $Map(\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^{m\times m})\rightarrow Map(\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^{m\times m})$ ? I think the problem is not how to compute the partial derivative.